# check for the completion of a SQL script

Tags: sql, automation, netezza

I want to automate a process that in its simplest form would involve running a sequence of SQL script. Each script depends on the results of the previous.
I use Netezza Aginity on a W7 box.
I can run one script with a command like:

```
Aginity.NetezzaWorkBench.exe -unattended -action exec -sqlfile "C:\Data\test.sql" -connstr "DSN=NZ_LAB" -stdout "c:\abc.txt" -stderr "c:\errors.txt"
```

How do I listen for the completion of the SQL query, and only at that point launch the following script?

I could just append all these script in one long script but that is not optimal because some of the scripts can be used as part of a different pipeline.
I could create a dummy table at the end of each process and a loop in the following script that looks for the existence of that table before continuing, but that seems like an overkill.

EDIT TO CLARIFY larger scope*************

Eventually the sequence of scripts will need to include non SQL script, i.e a Python script. So, whatever the solution might be, it needs to allow for that sort of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to set up a SQL Job and make each script a step, that way it will run sequentially. You can also set alerts on the job to let you know if it fails on a particular step, so you know where to look.  Really easy to do.

In the Object Explorer navigate to SQL Server Agent and then right click on Jobs and Create a new job.  It walks you through step by step.

Comment: Thanks. Would that framework allow to include non SQL scripts in the pipeline? Like: run SQL job, run second SQL job, run a Python script.

Comment: There is some flexibility.  if you select Type under Step name on the first screen you get when it opens the job creator, there are types that will run SSIS packages, Active X, etc.  There are several, hopefully one will meet your needs.